# Wacom - Bamboo Inkling, Spark... projecting image over HDMI or VGA on projector

Tags: graphics-tablet

I would like to buy a product like Wacom's [Inkling](http://inkling.wacom.eu/?/en/what_is_inkling/in_three_steps) or [Bamboo Spark](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/mobile-accessories/bamboo-spark). But I don't know if they support real-time image projection to a projector.

I only want to **write on paper** and at the same time project my drawing in real time to my students... Any idea on how to achieve that with above products or any other product which support this?

I am willing to invest around 300€.

Comment: Unfortunately, those devices *don't* give you real-time support, and none of the similar products that I know about do either unless you consider "smartboard"-type technology.  I have a couple of ideas in mind, but I have a few questions for you, first. Is the projector already attached to a computer?  Are you completely married to paper for technical reasons, or is there any way that you would consider arguments for instead writing on a digitizer tablet or a screen?  If you *are* married to paper, would you consider a doc cam?  How portable does your solution need to be?

Comment: I have Bamboo graphical tablet already and writing on a plastic surface just doesn't feel natural to me. The biggest problem is that I can't see what I am drawing and tablet is too thick - therefore my hand can't be in a natural writing position. We have a smart-board in our school  and this technology feels outdated, is not mobile and isn't a solution. The projector is always connected to my personal laptop (running desktop Linux) and until now I also connected my Bamboo tablet to it, then opened an application like Krita or MyPaint and lectured. Doc cam isn't an option.